# Powershell add element to each array in multidimensional array

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

Finding out how much fun arrays in `PowerShell` are compared to other languages.

Here's what I start with:
`$testArr = (1,2,3),(4,5,6)`

Here's what I want to end up with: `(1,2,3,0),(4,5,6,0)`

And what I've tried to get it: `foreach($x in $testArr) { $x += 0 }` and `$testArr | % { $_ += 0 }`

However, when I try to output `$testArr`, I get what I started with: `(1,2,3),(4,5,6)`.  I put a call to output the current array being worked with in the loop and see the `0` is in the array after adding it (`+= 0`), but for some reason, it doesn't want to stick around when I output the 2-D array.  What aspect of `PowerShell` arrays am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $testArr.Count; $i++) {$testArr[$i] += 0}
```

The point is that the arrays are actually of a fixed size.
Prove:

```
foreach($x in $testArr) { $x.Add(0) }
```

> Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size." At line:1 char:27
>   + foreach($x in $testArr) { $x.Add(0) }
>   +                           ~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException

In other words, when you use the `+=` assignment operator, you're actually creating a **copy** of the array and reassigning this to the variable.
Prove:

```
PS C:\> $a = 1,2,3
PS C:\> $b = $a
PS C:\> $a += 4
PS C:\> $a
1
2
3
4
PS C:\> $b
1
2
3
```

Meaning, you're creating a copy of `$x` which is no longer a reference to the items in the `$testArr`

Answer (score 0):

[iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57170938/11025476) describes the crux of the problem and that is arrays **cannot be resized**. If you want to add to a collection, you must choose a collection type that allows the length to be changed. Some common re-sizable types include generic lists and arraylists. An approach to allow you to change the size of a multi-dimensional collection could be to have an `[arraylist]` object that contains generic lists of `[int]` objects.

```
[collections.arraylist]$testArr = [collections.generic.list[int]](1,2,3),[collections.generic.list[int]](4,5,6)

$testArr
1
2
3
4
5
6

$testArr.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object

$testArr[0]
1
2
3

$testArr[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object

$testArr[0].Add(0)
$testArr[0]
1
2
3
0

$testArr[1].Add(0)
$testArr[1]

4
5
6
0
```

You can now refer to each sub-collection by their indexes `[0]` and `[1]` and augment them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it close to your way, with the caveat that += kills puppies.  I guess you didn't have the direct reference to the arrays.

```
foreach ($i in 0,1) { $testarr[$i] += 0 }
$testarr

1
2
3
0
4
5
6
0
```

You could also make it an array of 2 arraylists.

```
$a = [Collections.ArrayList](1,2,3),[Collections.ArrayList](4,5,6)
$a[0].add(0)
$a[1].add(0)
```